# Search number entries on a mysql database with COUNT

Tags: mysql, count

I have a mysql database which allocate:

```
iid, name, description, url, namecategory, idcategory, nametopic, idtopic
```

How can i know the number of entries that has `categoryid=1 and topicid=1`?

I've tried

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) 
                         FROM videos 
                        WHERE idcategory = 1 
                          AND idtopic = 1")
```

...but it hasn't worked!

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? How your result looks like?

Comment: no,any error. But if I comment // this line the file that I write with contents of database is ok. When i put this line, it doesn't writte any file, so the error is in this line.

Comment: not sure if it is a typo transferring across but there is no ; at the end of the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code and paste the result:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM videos WHERE idcategory=1 AND idtopic=1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result);
var_dump ($row);
```

Comment: Where does i get the result? I run my code from a webbrowser.

Comment: On screen. You should see something like:

array ('cnt' => X) Where X is number of records found

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); at begging of your code. Btw are you connected to mysql?

Comment: warning: mysql_fetch_asoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /../name.php on line ..

Comment: FUNCTION archivos.COUNT does not exist

Comment: I have a database called archivos that has Category Topic and videos. On videos database I have the items that I write on my question.

Comment: I guess that you have a space between COUNT and (id).

Comment: Great :) This what you should get

Comment: but now how can I get the number of rows? count the number of entries with idcat and idtop..??

Comment: You just did. Number of rows is available via $row['cnt'] in PHP.

Comment: ahm... ok, it works!! Thanks for the patience... I just start to use mysql databases...

Comment: Glad to help. btw you should accept helpful answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

you have stated that column names are `idcategory` and `idtopic`, and in the query you use `categoryid` and `topicid`.

Make those match and then try it out.

Comment: not work. In my file I write the names ok, but when i write on this computer i change the name....